# mysql query is returning incorrect values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data,

```
started ended   theDate     theYear themonth    growth  division    teams   status   location
2         0      8/31/2019  2019    8            2    Unknown       Team A  ACTIVE   Town A
1         0      5/31/1996  1996    5            1    Unknown       Team B  ACTIVE   Town A
1         0      8/31/2014  2014    8            1    Unknown       Team B  ACTIVE   Town B
1         0      1/31/1996  1996    1            1    Unknown       Team B  ACTIVE   Town C
1         0      7/31/2004  1985    7            1    Unknown       Team C  ACTIVE   Town E
1         0      7/31/1985  1985    7            1    Unknown       Team B  ACTIVE   Town A
1         0      5/31/2019  2019    5            1    Unknown       Team A  ACTIVE   Town F
```

The started column shows the employees that have joined on that particular date. The growth column is started - ended where ended is the number of employees that left.

I have the following query which will extract the data correctly as long as i specifiy the variables.

```
set @theYear = 2019 ;
set @team = 'Team A' ;


SELECT 
    t1.growth,
    SUM(t2.growth) AS Emp_Count,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.theYear IS NULL THEN t1.theYear
        ELSE t1.theYear
    END AS theYear,
     t1.team,
    t1.location,
    t1.division,
    t1.status,
    CASE
        WHEN t1.Month = 1 THEN 'JAN'
        WHEN t1.Month = 2 THEN 'FEB'
        WHEN t1.Month = 3 THEN 'MAR'
        WHEN t1.Month = 4 THEN 'APR'
        WHEN t1.Month = 5 THEN 'MAY'
        WHEN t1.Month = 6 THEN 'JUN'
        WHEN t1.Month = 7 THEN 'JUL'
        WHEN t1.Month = 8 THEN 'AUG'
        WHEN t1.Month = 9 THEN 'SEP'
        WHEN t1.Month = 10 THEN 'OCT'
        WHEN t1.Month = 11 THEN 'NOV'
        WHEN t1.Month = 12 THEN 'DEC'
    END AS myMONTH
FROM
    (SELECT 
        CASE
                WHEN r.growth IS NOT NULL THEN r.growth
                WHEN r.growth IS NULL THEN 0
            END AS growth,
            r.theYear,
            r.team,
            r.division,
            r.location,
            t.mon_num AS Month,
            r.status
    FROM
        Reports r
    RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1 mon_num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) t ON t.mon_num = r.themonth
        AND r.theYear =  (select @theYear)
        AND r.team = (select @team)
    GROUP BY r.growth , Month
    ORDER BY t.mon_num ASC) AS t1
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        CASE
                WHEN r2.growth IS NOT NULL THEN r2.growth
                WHEN r2.growth IS NULL THEN 0
            END AS growth,
            r2.theYear,
            r2.team,
            r2.division,
            r2.location,
            t.mon_num AS Month,
            r2.status
    FROM
        Reports r2
    RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1 mon_num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) t ON t.mon_num = r2.themonth
        AND r2.theYear = (select @theYear)
        AND r2.team = (select @team)
    GROUP BY r2.growth , Month
    ORDER BY t.mon_num ASC) AS t2 ON t1.Month >= t2.Month
GROUP BY t1.Month;
```

As you can see below the query will list the months i.e Jan,feb etc along with the selected data along with the incremental count.

[image]

However if I want to use the query without the variables i.e. get all data without any conditions/filters the result i get is incorrect. First off it should start with the year 1985 as i do have the year 1985 in my dataset.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data and desired results (perhaps simplified).  Your query seems much more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Your query is broken.  The `GROUP BY` conditions do not match the `SELECT` conditions.  I really recommend that you start over, as I suggested in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a complex query. A wise programmer troubleshoots that sort of thing a subquery at a time.

Your query contains this code:

```
        AND r.theYear =  (select @theYear)
```

What is this supposed to do if your @-variable is not defined?

Do you want something like this instead?

```
 AND (@theYear IS NULL OR r.theYear=@theYear)
```

That will not filter by year if your @-variable is NULL.

Comment: Yes it will not, which is what i want to do. I want to remove the conditions. Right now the query works fine when conditions are specified. I want it to work in both cases.

Comment: the answer provided does work but it provides me with the same output I am getting right now. As i mentioned earlier I would like the query to provide me the correct results whether i specified conditions/filters or not.